# converting a quosure to a string in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I've been using quosures with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

thing <- quo(clarity)
diamonds %>% select(!!thing)
print(paste("looking at", thing))
```

> [1] "looking at ~"       "looking at clarity"

I really want to print out the string value put into the quo, but can only get the following:

```
print(thing)
```

> <quosure: global>
>
> ~clarity

```
print(thing[2])
```

> clarity()

```
substr(thing[2],1, nchar(thing[2]))
```

> [1] "clarity"

is there a simpler way to "unquote" a quo()?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We can use `quo_name`

```
print(paste("looking at", quo_name(thing)))
```

Answer (score 10):

If you use within a function, you will need to `enquo()` it first. Note also that with newer versions of rlang, `as_name()` seems to be preferred!

```r
library(rlang)
fo <- function(arg1= name) {
  print(rlang::quo_text(enquo(arg1)))
  print(rlang::as_name(enquo(arg1)))
  print(rlang::quo_name(enquo(arg1)))
}

fo()  
#> [1] "name"
#> [1] "name"
#> [1] "name"
```

Answer (score 9):

`quo_name` does not work if the quosure is too long:

```
> q <- quo(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z)
> quo_name(q)
[1] "+..."
```

`rlang::quo_text` (not exported by `dplyr`) works better, but introduces line breaks (which can be controlled with parameter `width`):

```
> rlang::quo_text(q)
[1] "a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + \n    q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z"
```

Otherwise, `as.character` can also be used, but returns a vector of length two.  The second part is what you want:

```
> as.character(q)
[1] "~"                                                                                                    
[2] "a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z"
> as.character(q)[2]
[1] "a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z"
```