# Convert object name to string in tidyverse chain within anonymous function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to convert an object name to a string within an anonymous function. First, I need to call the object normally within a dplyr chain, then use the object's name.

I've tried a number of methods to solve my problem but I'm unsure why they're not working. I've succeeded when calling an object directly, but not within a function in a map/lapply chain.

I've checked the three following pages:
[In R, how to get an object's name after it is sent to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function)

[How to convert variable (object) name into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string)

[converting a quosure to a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932310/converting-a-quosure-to-a-string-in-r)

Here's some stripped down sample work to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish and what I've tried so far.

**Data (3 tibbles):**

```
a18 <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3), 
            y = c(1,2,3))
a19 <- tibble(x = c(1,2,3), 
            y = c(1,2,3))

dat <- 
structure(list(ID = c("12327701006", "12327601004", "12327601006", 
                      "12327601008", "12327701008", "12327701009", "12327701010", "12327701011", 
                      "12326201002", "12334201009"), GRP = c("169", "169", "169", "169", 
                                                             "169", "169", "169", "169", "170", "169"), Stat = c(8.8981219, 
                                                                                                                 4.25978943, 9.17077178, 4.13070278, 9.38120484, 4.32074928, 4.60516953, 
                                                                                                                 4.60194847, 14.23145155, 5.00784539)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**Attempt**

```
lapply(list(a18, a19), 
       function(x) (dat %>% 
                      group_by(GRP) %>% 
                      summarize(Stat = sum(Stat)) %>% 
                      ungroup() %>% 
                      mutate(Year = paste0("20", stringr::str_sub(rlang::quo_text(quo(x)), start = -2)))) )
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
GRP    Stat Year
<chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 169    54.4 20x
2 170    14.2 20x

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
GRP    Stat Year
<chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 169    54.4 20x
2 170    14.2 20x
```

Here's the output I need. It includes the full year, such as "2018" instead of "20x".

**Desired Output**

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
GRP    Stat Year
<chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 169    54.4 2018
2 170    14.2 2018

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
GRP    Stat Year
<chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 169    54.4 2019
2 170    14.2 2019
```

I don't understand why it's not working because when I do the following outside of the `lapply` call, it works, returning "18" instead of "x".

```
stringr::str_sub(rlang::quo_text(quo(a18)), -2)
[1] "18"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `imap` on a `named` `list` (which we get if we wrap with `lst`, remove the non-numeric part with `str_remove` and `paste` (or `str_c`) with the "20"

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
imap(lst(a18, a19), ~ 
     dat %>% 
         group_by(GRP) %>%
         summarize(Stat = sum(Stat)) %>%
         mutate(Year = str_c("20", str_remove(.y, "\\D+"))))
```

Or with `str_replace`

```
imap(lst(a18, a19), ~ 
 dat %>% 
     group_by(GRP) %>%
     summarize(Stat = sum(Stat)) %>%
     mutate(Year = str_replace(.y, "\\D+", "20")))
#$a18
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  GRP    Stat Year 
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1 169    54.4 2018 
#2 170    14.2 2018 

#$a19
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  GRP    Stat Year 
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1 169    54.4 2019 
#2 170    14.2 2019
```

Or if we use `list`

```
list(a18 = a18, a19= a19)
```

Or another option is `mget`

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^a\\d+"))
```

---

Regarding why the `quo()` is not working, it is taking that as literal 'x'. instead of the value stored in it

```
stringr::str_sub(rlang::quo_text(quo(x)), -2)
#[1] "x"
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. One question, what is the "\\D+" in the `stringr` call for?

Comment: @hmhensen That was just to remove all non-numeric values (i.le. one or more characters not a digit).  If you have only. 'a', then simply `str_remove(.y, "a")`

Comment: @hmhensen. I would make use of `imap` or `map2` (by also passing names) instead of applying a lot of evaluations (as these are already optimized for these kind of operations)

Comment: That's the next step. I'm trying to incorporate `map2` into more of my work, but I don't run into these situations too often.